# Ubuntu 18 and 20 GUI/Mouse strange behaviour

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, gui

From time to time, my Ubuntu glitches and start behaving weird. After the 'glitch' happens, I can open the dashboard, can't click programs in the sidebar, and can't right click.The top menu is also unresponsive. First I noticed this bug on Ubuntu 18, and after I upgraded to 20, it worked well till yesterday.
Here are my observations:

- It's not hardware related, tried external mouse.
- Rebooting the system helps,but now always, have to keep rebooting
  till I can right click on the desktop
- Restarting mouse service doesn't help

  ```
  sudo modprobe -r usbhid && sudo modprobe -r psmouse
  ```
- Installing updates doesn't work

However I can correctly use some programs, Firefox for example, works.Everything except the right click
I can reproduce this bug, putting the PC in sleep and wake up, it appears every time.

I also noticed : for example, firefox in the background and gedit in the foreground,when I click something in gedit, instead firefox gets clicked
Also firefox works fine, but not the close,resize,and minimize buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command to install the Synaptics driver:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

This command worked in my laptop.

Comment: Will let you know if that worked

Comment: first you check input list (xinput list) and install list (apt list --installed) using given terminal command. and check (xserver-xorg-input-synaptics) this synaptics driver if this is not installed then you can try above command.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem. Does anyone have an idea?